# What is wrong with this perl script

Tags: oracle, perl, sqlplus

Below is the Perl script that I have written

```
my $COUNT_1;
my $parameter1 = 'PU_CLERK';
$COUNT_1 = `sqlplus -s hr/password\@dbname\@sql_script.sql $parameter1`;
```

SQL SCRIPT:

```
select count(*) from employees
where job_id <> '&1'
and salary > 9000
and commission_pct is not null
order by first_name desc
/
exit;
```

When I run this query by passing the argument &1 it is giving me a string with an error message. But when I run the same query by hardcoding I'm getting the output properly (the count is 15 which is the correct answer).

```
select count(*) from employees
where job_id <> 'PU_CLERK'
and salary > 9000
and commission_pct is not null
order by first_name desc
/
exit;
```

I'm not able to understand where I'm going wrong. How do I pass parameters in Perl. We used to do the same way in shell script and it was working absolutely fine.

EDIT:

This is the error message im getting

```
 perl call_sql.pl
value of first variable isold   2: whe
re job_id <> '&1'
 new   2: where job_id <> 'PU_CLERK'
    15
```

So its basically not printing the 15 value its printing all those string also when i use '&1' in my sql script

EDIT2:

Hi Guys finally it is working. In my sql code instead of giving '&1' i gave '$1' Now i want to know is $1 of some significance in Perl? Thanks..

Comment: Why not use the [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) module instead?

Comment: If you're calling an external program from perl, you can't just type in the command. You need to execute it somehow. See [how to execute external programs](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands).

Comment: Hi, TLP i don't know how to use DBI :(

Comment: Hi alarmed, Im actually able to execute the perl script . If you see i called the sql script and was able to print the output in the second case. i just forgot to put backticks here in this question. Problem is not with the execution . Its with the parameters im passing.

Comment: Set up a DBI object, open a connection, prepare a query, using `?` (no quotes) as placeholder for args, then execute and fetch records. There should be examples in the documentation I linked.

Comment: @user2647888 Congratulations, knowing what you don't know is the first step.

Comment: What is the error message then?

Comment: Hi RobEarl, Sry Don't get me wrong I'm very new to perl script and i'm almost close to get the output in this above case i feel. Just im stuck on passing parameters. Now if i go to DBI then it will take a lot of time for me to understand which i will definitely do for my next script.

Comment: It looks like you need to remove the quotes around `&1`.

Comment: Hi TLP quotes is required around `&1` or else it will throw an error as invalid identifier since any string should be enclosed in quotes in oracle

Comment: @user2647888 Well, my advice is to use the DBI module. It might take you a while to set up, but then you always have a solid tool to use.

Comment: Does it work if you run `$COUNT_1 = sqlplus -s hr/password\@dbname\@sql_script.sql PU_CLERK`?

Comment: its working when i directl give PU_CLRK in the sql statement

Comment: Does it run if you do `sqlplus -s hr/password...script.sql PU_CLERK` from the command line?

Comment: I hope you realise that you need a space before the SQL file name? It should look like this `\`sqlplus -s  hr/password\@dbname  \@sql_script.sql  $parameter1\``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the answer to your current problem, but using the [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) module is the better solution, so I wrote a sample script to get you started. You may need to tweak some things to get it to work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbname  = "mydb";
my $user    = "foo";
my $passwd  = "bar";

my $dbh     = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$dbname", $user, $passwd)
                  or die $DBI::errstr;

my $parameter1  = 'PU_CLERK';

my $statement   = "select count(*) from employees
where job_id <> ?
and salary > 9000
and commission_pct is not null
order by first_name desc";
my $sth     = $dbh->prepare($statement) or die $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute($parameter1) or die $sth->errstr;

while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) {
    print "@$row";   # or whatever you want to do with it
}

$dbh->disconnect or warn $dbh->errstr;
```

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing with perl.

Proof: make an shell script, say `mytest.sh` with the next content:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$0: Got $# args" >&2   #to stderr
i=0
for arg
do
    let i++
    echo "$0: arg($i)=$arg=" >&2 #to stderr
done
echo "15" #result to stdout
```

make it executable, with `chmod 755 mytest.sh`

Now modify your perl script as:

```
my $COUNT_1;
my $parameter1 = 'PU_CLERK';
$COUNT_1 = `./mytest.sh -s hr/password\@dbname\@sql_script.sql $parameter1`;
print "script returned: $COUNT_1\n";
```

run it

```
$ perl script.pl
```

result:

```
./mytest.sh: Got 3 args
./mytest.sh: arg(1)=-s=
./mytest.sh: arg(2)=hr/password@dbname@sql_script.sql=
./mytest.sh: arg(3)=PU_CLERK=
script returned: 15
```

e.g. the `perl`

- correctly run the external script
- correctly passes the arguments to it
- so, search for the error in the `sqlplus` doccumentation...

Comment: yeah jm666 im running it from windows actaully.

Comment: @user2647888 unfortunately i can't make an windows.cmd file to test it